# Recursively traversing controls In OnInit disables GridView RowCommand and loses Viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

If I recursively traverse the controls of a page, the RowCommand event is no longer fired by LinkButtons in a GridView.  In fact, it looks like the ViewState for the GridView is lost.  Why?  How can I work around this?

The code below will work fine until you uncomment the `//recurse(this.Controls)` line.  Then, when you hit the link, the GridView disappears and the RowCommand is never fired.

The complete `<body>` of my page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" onrowcommand="gv_RowCommand">
        <Columns><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link"><ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" CommandArgument = 'xxx'>xxx</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField></Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

My code behind:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        //recurse(this.Controls);
    }
    private static void recurse(ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
            recurse(control.Controls);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Link", typeof(string));
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Link"] = "google.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(dt);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            gv.DataSource = ds;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Application["counter"] == null)
            this.Application["counter"] = 0;
        this.Application["counter"] = (int)this.Application["counter"] + 1;
        Response.Write("JUNK" + this.Application["counter"]);
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish using the `recurse`?

Comment: In my real code I am searching for some controls by name so I can set their attributes appropriately.  The code in OnInit is clearing them out. They are also be accessed later (in Page_Load and such), but those recursive searches work fine.

Comment: Where are you setting those controls' attributes? If we know what you are trying to achieve, you can give you alternative solution.

Comment: @user12861 You are going to have to include the real `recurse` function for us to help you.

Comment: @Magnus you don't need the real recurse function to explain why this is causing a problem anyway.  The problem is in the code I gave.  If I knew the reason I might be able to think of a reasonable workaround myself.

Comment: @Win What I'm trying to achieve is setting some error messages on the page.  I want to override the standard error controls where they usually show up and make them show up elsewhere (there's actually a master page involved and I want to use controls on the regular page instead of the master).  The problem is that this is part of a large existing code base that I did not write.  A workaround like moving this code out of OnInit and into OnLoad would be much more intrusive.  If I could understand the cause of the problem, I might be able to think of a non-intrusive workaround myself.

Comment: seems like you are not the only one having this problem, see http://forums.asp.net/t/1043999.aspx/1

Comment: @jbl That's exactly what I wanted.  I'm going to post it as an answer, but if you want some reputation you can post it as well and I'll vote you up and accept it.

Comment: Having battled in the comments, you deserve posting the answer ;-) Thx anyway. Glad I have been of some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jbl found something that explained this well enough for me (thanks for the search skills!).  This problem has been seen before here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1043999.aspx/1

Summarizing that page, accessing the `.Controls` property of a GridView in any way during the Init phase will destroy its ViewState.  There is no explanation for why, but it has been observed anyway.

There is a workaround on that page that is good enough for me.  If you check for each control to see if it `.HasControls()` and don't access its `.Controls` property if it doesn't, the ViewState will not be lost, and consequently events will fire normally.

P.S.  I'm GUESSING this is a bug, but of course it can't be changed forevermore because of backwards compatibility :(