# Why does FindControl sometimes find nothing inside a FormView in a UserControl?

Tags: asp.net

I have a `FormView` in an ASP.NET UserControl. The `EditItemTemplate` contains some controls, and I'd like to run some code server-side whenever they are created, to set some values based on some conditions.

It appears that the `Control.Load` and `PreRender` events are unsuitable for this, since the control can sometimes be rendered without any child controls (not sure why that happens). Specifically, if I look at `FormView.ChildControlsCreated` in the debugger, I always see `True`, but when I try to `FindControl` by name, sometimes it's there and sometimes it isn't.

When should I execute my code that requires access to the inner controls?

Comment: could it be the same kind of issue as this one with GridView ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15414284/1236044

Comment: @jbl that is definitely related - if I `FindControl` something before changing the form mode, this seems to permanently break the controls collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `FormViewMode` is sometimes different. There is no template for `ReadOnlyMode`, so whenever the form is in that mode, `FindControl` doesn't find anything.