# Asp.net -firing control before page completes rendering causes 404 error

Tags: asp.net, gridview, http-status-code-404, undefined, paging

Could anyone please give me some background info on this please, it is breaking my head.
This does not happen on localhost (Windows 7) when developing, but on Windows 2003 IIS 6.

I have a lot of controls (dropdownlists/text boxes) and a gridview on this specific page.

Two scenarios causing same problem:

1) The HTML of the gridview is near the top, and (thus) renders first to the client.
When the gridview is displayed - it happens that some of the other dropdownlists are not rendered yet - but some are. When I page the gridview before all the dropdownlists are rendered I get a 404 error - the pagename is 'unknown' - I also (and I can't explain why but eventviewer only fires it sometimes - not everytime) get the following in Event Viewer:

```
Event code: 4009 
Event message: Viewstate verification failed. Reason: Viewstate was invalid.
```

2) When the first few dropdownlists have rendered (at this point the other dropdownlists have not rendered to the screen yet) - and I select a different gridview item and submit - then I also get the 404 error.
http://mysite.com/undefined

This only happens on one specific content page - even though the exact same controls are used on other pages. On other pages I can change pages before the controls are all rendered - without error.

When I put the HTML of the gridview at the bottom of the page, it renders last. I thus cannot page before the rendering of the other controls have completed and this workaround saves the day - but only for the gridview. Scenario 2 is still very possible.

Questions:
Where would I be able to catch this error? In which event please?

Is this expected behavior? I can understand that the Viewstate error can occur - but why only sometimes does the viewstate get written to the Event Viewer?

Is this a problem for other developers too? Do you take steps like rendering controls in specific order in order to prevent errors like this?

Comment: This might happen if you navigate your GridView controls during init stage, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15415480/1236044